# How to make Jupyter notebook python help function output colorful?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Jupyter notebook and trying to see the some help about the functions. For example, when I print the help of `statsmodels.OLS` I got the following plain black and white help.

Are there any python modules that colorize/beautify the `help` outputs?

For example:

- hightlight parameters names
- highlight the code example in python syntax hightlight
- and so on.

If there are not some modules, what would be the starting point, to colorize the parameters and the python codes?

The example output of `help` is given below:

[image]

Comment: The `sm.OSL` you shown for example has docstring that look like [this](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py#L820) which is just about the same as shown in `help`

Comment: The help function is just printing the docstrings or the `__doc__` in the object. Because people write docstrings differently there isn't any way to accurately determine what is the parameters or even the example code. So I don't think easy solution to colorize it other than write the docs with ANSI escape code.

Comment: The closest I can think of is dedicated IDE like Pycharm or VSCode will detect words like `>>>` or `params:` and highlight them. But obviously they don't work if the docstring is written differently or doesn't even exist.

Comment: I was thinking highlighting at least numpystyle and googlestyle docstrings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to beautify the help using [rich library](https://github.com/willmcgugan/rich) (in jupyter, you can install it, using the command `!pip install rich`).
In particular, you could study the [inspect method](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/init.html#rich.inspect).

For example, with the following code:

```
from rich import inspect
inspect(sm.OLS, help=True)
```

I get this output:
[image: rich inspect output]